# If $A$ is the generator of $(P_t)$, then $A+f$ is the generator of $(P_t^f)$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, lebesgue-integral, markov-chains, markov-process

Let $X=(X_t)_{t\geq0}$ be a Markov process on a state space $\Gamma$ (a Hausdorff topological vector space), let $A$ be the [infinitesimal generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal_generator_%28stochastic_processes%29#Definition) of $X$ and let $\mathcal C(\Gamma)$ the space of continuous functions on $\Gamma$. Then for each continuous function $f \in \mathcal C(\Gamma)$ the operator $A+f$ is the infinitesimal generator of the semigroup $(P_t^f)_{t\geq0}$ defined by
\begin{equation*}
P_t^f g(x) = \mathbb E_x\left[\mathrm \exp\left\{\int_0^t f(X_s) ds\right\} g(X_t) \right], \qquad g \in \mathcal C(\Gamma), x \in \Gamma,
\end{equation*}
where $\mathbb E_x$ denotes the expectation with respect to the process $X$ starting in $x \in \Gamma$.

In other words:

> **Show**
>   \begin{equation*}
> \lim_{t\rightarrow0} \frac{1}{t} \left( \mathbb E_x\left[\mathrm \exp\left\{\int_0^t f(X_s) ds\right\} g(X_t) \right] - g(x) \right)
> = Ag(x)  + f(x) g(x).\tag1
> \end{equation*}

In a proof I'm studying I found this stated as a known fact about Markov processes, but I couldn't find any suitable reference and my knowledge about continuous Markov processes is limited.

> **My question**: Why and under which assumptions about $X$ and $\Gamma$ is (1) true?

(In the case I encountered it, $\Gamma$ is actually finite.)

On a further note, does the semigroup $(P_t^f)$ bear any deeper meaning? The definition first seemed quite arbitrary to me, but the fact that this statement should be generally known makes it seem like there's more to it than I realise...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write 
\begin{equation*}
 \frac{1}{t} \left( \mathbb E_x\left[\mathrm e^{\,\int_0^t f(X_s) ds}  g(X_t) \right] - g(x) \right)
= \mathbb E_x\left[{\mathrm  e^{\,\int_0^t f(X_s) ds} -1\over t}\, g(X_t) \right] +\mathbb{E}_x\left[{g(X_t)-g(x)\over t}\right].
\end{equation*}
Letting $t\downarrow 0$, the right hand side becomes $f(x)g(x)+Ag(x).$ 
You will want to assume that $f,g$ are bounded continuous functions, that $g\in{\cal D}(A)$ and that $(X_t)$ has right continuous sample paths, almost surely.

Provided that $f\leq 0,$ $A+f$ generates the Markov process which is the $A$ process with "killing" function $f$.

Comment: @Amarus Just differentiate the function $\exp(\int_0^t f(X_s)\,ds)$.

Comment: [Sorry, I just deleted my comment because I couldn't edit it. Here it was:] A silly question: To see that $1/t (\exp\{\int_0^t f(X_s) ds\}-1) \rightarrow f(x)$  for $t \rightarrow 0$ we just use L'Hôpital's rule and FTC, right? Thanks for your answer and also your corrections!

Comment: @First comment: Of course, you are right, it is just the derivative at $t=0$ again. :)

Comment: @Amarus No problem. The theory of Markov processes, their generators and semigroups is very technical, so it is worthwhile checking all the details thoroughly!

Comment: Your last remark (in your answer) made me think about the properties of the Markov process that is generated by $A+f$. Does it share "most" properties with $X$? I know it's not an exact question, but I'm not sure how to phrase it. I'm pretty sure that this process should inherit a lot of properties from $X$, like irreducibility for example, although I can't think of a proof right now.